# Alternate for spring batch

Tags: scheduled-tasks, azure-cosmosdb, batch-processing

I have a batch requirement to read from cosmos db, check for specific condition if it matches then I need to modify few fields and update back to cosmos. Other than spring batch, what are other best approaches available?

Answer (score 0):

The alternatives to spring batch are **Hadoop**, **Apache Spark** and **Kafka**. All these 3 technologies can be integrated with Cosmos DB with connectors and designed to enable the development of robust batch applications vital for the daily operations of enterprise systems.

Refer to below official Microsoft documents for each technology and learn how they work.

**Apache Spark:** [Azure Cosmos DB Apache Spark 2 OLTP Connector for Core (SQL) API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-api-sdk-java-spark#:%7E:text=The%20Spark%20Connector%20allows%20you,and%20stream%20processing%20are%20supported.&text=This%20connector%20supports%20the%20core,the%20MongoDB%20Connector%20for%20Spark.)

**Hadoop:** [Hadoop Connector for Azure Cosmos DB](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-hadoop/blob/master/README.md)

**Kafka:** [Kafka Connect for Azure Cosmos DB - Sink connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/kafka-connector-sink)